# Sympy Set Theory - How to reduce mathematical expressions?

Tags: python, set, logic, sympy, set-theory

Let's say I have `n` Sympy sets defined. The set `s`is:

```
s = FiniteSet('red', 'yellow', 'green')
```

Then I have three further sets:

```
a = FiniteSet('red')
b = FiniteSet('yellow')
c = FiniteSet('green')
```

It is obvious that `a`, `b` and `c` are subsets of `s`.
When I let sympy calculate the `Union` of those three subsets, I would obtain the `s`
But sympy gives as output:

```
>>>Union(a,b,c)
{'green', 'yellow', 'red'}
```

I would like to get `s` as a result.

Is there a way to achieve that with `Sympy`?

Comment: The short answer is no but perhaps if you pose your problem a bit differently there is a way to achieve whatever it is you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to have a Gestalt Shift in your expectations. You are working in Python and you have assigned values to variables. Your expection is that when you print a variable `d` that has the same value as variable `s` that you will see the variable `s` -- but that's not what `print(variable)` does: it prints the value, not a list of any/all variables that are the same.

But you can ask SymPy if the two variables have the same values:

```py
>>> d == s
True
```

You could also look through `locals()` (carefully) to find which name has the same value as `d`:

```py
>>> L = locals()  # a dictionary of names and values
>>> [i for i in L if i != 'd' and type(L.get(i,None)) == type(d) and L[i] == d]
['s']
```

(But *anything* in `locals` that matches will be printed, not only `s`.)